# How to create an infinity mirror effect in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

I've been able to do this in cycles fairly easily with a mix of glass and mirror material, but obviously eevee has it's own challenges with reflection and glass. However, with some tweaking and using nodes, I was able to get a close approximation of mirror and glass in eevee. The issue is though that it doesn't even come close to the effect that cycles produces. Screenspace reflections and refraction is turned on. The effect is produced with a mirror and glass plane with another plain mirror plane and Suzanne sandwiched in between. Any thoughts on how this could work?

Here is a sample render in eevee:

[image]

Here is how it looks in cycles:

[image]

Node setup for the mirror film glass:

[image]

Simple node setup for the regular mirror:

[image]

I've attached the .blend

[image]